# Why doesn't this C# generic delegate assign?

Tags: c#, generics

I want a reference to a delegate that returns an instance of a generic interface, where the type parameter is covariant. If I specify the type of `T` when calling `Get` then it compiles ok. But within `Get`, I can't make what looks like an equivalent assignment - despite `T` being constrained to `IItem`.

It says...

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func<MyNamespace.A>' to
> 'System.Func<MyNamespace.IA<MyNamespace.IItem>>'. An explicit
> conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Why is this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public interface IA<out T>
    {
        IEnumerable<T> f();
    }
    
    public class A<T> : IA<T>
    {
        public IEnumerable<T> f()
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        }
    }
    
    public interface IItem {}
    public class Item : IItem {}
    
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            Func<IA<IItem>> a = Get<Item>();
        }
        
        public static Func<IA<T>> Get<T>() where T : IItem
        {
            var x = () => new A<T>();
            
            //Doesn't compile
            Func<IA<IItem>> a = x;
            
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Covariance only works for reference types - which would cause a problem for your code if `T` were a value type implementing `IItem`.

All you need to do in order to make your code compile is constrain `T` to be a reference type:

```cs
public static Func<IA<T>> Get<T>() where T : class, IItem
```

As a slightly simpler example (with fewer generics), we can use `IConvertible` which is implemented by both `string` and `int`:

```cs
Func<string> x = () => "";
Func<int> y = () => 0;

// This is fine, as string is a
// reference type implementing IConvertible
Func<IConvertible> x2 = x;

// This doesn't compile, because the
// covariant conversion isn't available:
// int is a value type (even though it
// implements IConvertible)
Func<IConvertible> y2 = y;
```

Comment: "All you need to do in order to make your code compile is constrain T to be a *value* type"...
Did you mean reference type?

Comment: @DaveShaw: Yup, fixing, thanks.